# Postflop guidelines

Tags: heads-up

I am currently trying to expand my knowledge of hyper-turbo heads-up SNG (stacks starting at about 25BB)

It is pretty easy to find GTO charts for pre-flop ranges, both from the SB and the BB, but postflop is a different story. At this point, I only know the basics of c-betting and that's pretty much it.

Could you give me a quick summary of the fundamentals (or link me to where I can find that info) behind the other possible post-flop movements? I am referring to things like double/triple-barreling, check-calling vs check-raising the flop, donk-betting and so on.

I would also be interested in understanding the dynamics of limped pots

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty expansive set of knowledge that you are asking for, and it would be hard to cover all of it in one answer. I can help you get to some resources that might lead you to finding out more about what you are looking for.

You can read some books about this subject, there are a ton out there and there is certainly enough information to write a book on the subject. I personally like Mastering Small Stakes NLHE by Johnathan Little. I am studying it now and I find that although it is not a complete solution to postflop play, it gives some good guidelines and starting points to develop your own train of thought.

There are lots of other books out there but I dont have them off the top of my head as I am posting this. If books are not your thing, you can watch videos of people playing heads up. This includes twitch streams, youtube videos, and even forum posts would probably fall into this category. Take note of what the players are doing in different situations and try to find a way to justify it or find a reason that another line would be better.

There are lots of resources out there, I think if you are looking for a very specific situation a book would be best starting point to get some fundamentals down.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many different ways to handle post flop. There is no one single way. I love mathematics so I prefer the mathematical way.

My way to learn about post flop analysis is to use some form of a calculator. This can potentially help to train your mind to identify good setups. As for the betting part, my strategy is typically to follow the [Kelly citerion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion).

Once you know you odds and how much to bet, you just need to come up with the right type of play to sway your opponents into the right direction. This could either be pretending to be weak or pretending to be strong.

The app I built and use to help me learn this is [Edge.poker](https://app.edge.poker/).

Comment: I am familiar with the math, and this approach is interesting, but it still runs into the issue of estimating the villain's range